# C uninitialized local variable used when variable is in scope

Tags: c, initialization

For whatever reason I am unable to decipher why the compiler is throwing the uninitialized local variable exception based on a few methods I've tried. My current code is as follows.

```
while (fgets(line, LINE_SIZE, fh) != NULL)
{
    const char s[1] = " ";
    char * token;
    token = strtok(line, s);
    char * tokptr;

    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_NUM; i++)
    {
        nums[i] = *token;
    }

    while (token != NULL)
    {
        strcpy(tokptr, token);
        token = strtok(NULL, s);

    }
}
```

I'm receiving an error at the line: `strcpy(tokptr, token)` for an uninitialized local variable 'tokptr' and I'm lost as to why.

I've tried pre-allocating the memory for the variable by using `char * tokptr = malloc(200);` but have also not had any luck with that.

Comment: You do know that the string literal `" "` is actually ***two*** characters? The space, and the ***null-terminator*** that's needed by all string functions to find the end of the string. Initializing a one-character array like that will not include the terminator, leading all string function you pass the array to to go out of bounds.

Comment: As for your problem: Where is `tokptr` pointing? The initialization you show should have solved the problem (with the compiler warning message).

Comment: `char * tokptr = malloc(200);`  Should have worked.  What problem did you have with that?

Comment: I'm very new to C and pointers, so my usage on them is very ambiguous. i'm trying to follow the requirements for the methods, and I'm not sure where it's going wrong. Could you explain possibly what it should be pointing to? `tokptr` just needs to store the char string from `token`. `token` is filled just fine by the `strtok(NULL, S)` method.

Comment: I'm guessing the problem is that, assuming a reasonable level of smartness, the compiler can deduce that the call to `strtok` will read memory assigned to `tokptr`, which has not been initialized. Changing the order of declaration of the local variables could shed light on this.

Comment: Even if you allocate space for `tokptr`, you don't do anything with it after you've filled it with the contents of `token`, not least of which `free`ing it...so what's the point of it?

Comment: @dbush I run into a runtime error when I use `char * tokptr = malloc(200);` With the expression: buffer != nullptr

Comment: What is `nullptr`? Do you compile with a C++ compiler?

Comment: No, I'm using VS 2015, but I've set everything to use C compiler, so I thought?

Comment: "I'm receiving an error at the line: strcpy(tokptr, token) for an uninitialized local variable 'tokptr' and I'm lost as to why."  That would be because tokptr is an uninitialized local variable.

Comment: @Lundin Thank you for stating the obvious. But clearly, by my question I'm referring to why it is considered uninitialized when I have stated that I've tried pre-allocating the memory and seeing how memory is allocated for it, I am trying to copy the contents of `token` into `tokptr`, then the error is being thrown.

Comment: What do you want to do with `tokptr` and `strcpy(tokptr, token);` and `nums[i] = *token;`?

Comment: @Justin mallocing space for `tokptr` fixes the warning.  If you get a runtime error, you did something else wrong.

Comment: @Justin Then you need to update your question with the real code, in the form of a [mcve]. As it stands, you just try to copy data into an uninitialized pointer.

Comment: I'm guessing you think that declaring a variable `char* tokptr` allocates memory. It does, for the _pointer itself_. Not for the _pointed-at_ data. See the linked duplicate.

Comment: @Justin, if you insist that you get an error when in fact you are initializing variable `tokptr`, then I suggest you update your question to present *that* code as your MCVE, along with whatever warning or error the compiler reports for it.  The problem with the code currently presented is exactly what the compiler says: `tokptr` is not initialized.

Comment: @Lundin I looked at the linked duplicate. It helped me figure out the answer, thank you. I'd not have known to search for that, as I am rather new to C. Sorry for the misunderstanding.